# WPF Run storyboard on MouseLeave event

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, expression-blend

[image: Application Menu image]

I am writing an application for use at work to display helpful information. My job is to troubleshoot computers at multiple sites in different states. The application is broken into a list of Buttons, one for each state, and and a sub menu listbox of sites in that state. The buttons are along the left side of the application and a ListBox Menu opens to the right side of the button. I have templated the Menu Buttons and Listbox for consistancy. On Button MouseEnter a storyboard runs that shows the ListBox of Sites. If the mouse moves over the Menu the Menu will stay open until the mouse leaves. The problem is that if the mouse does not enter the menu and just moves over the buttons each buttons menu opens but does not close until you mouse over the menu and then leave.
The menu should only be open while over the button that called it or the menu itself and close upon entering a different button. I thought about a condition of if the mouse is not over "Button 1 or Menu 1" then close "Menu 1" and so on for each button/menu combo but I am not sure how to do it.

I was thinking it could be done with a multitrigger in my ListBox style but I am not sure how. I can do the MouseLeave event trigger but am not sure how to also declare that the mouse is not over the Button that goes with the menu. I am pretty new to programming and would really like some help.

Answer (score 0):

Not best way I think. But you can try this.

- First. You should bind some properties to the buttons and listbox menu `IsMouseOver` properties.
- Second. In every button you should add `Style` with `MultiDataTrigger` in `Style.Triggers` like this. There the `Butt1IsMouseOver` and `Menu1IsMouseOver` are these binded properties.

  ```
  <Style.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding Butt1IsMouseOver}" Value="False" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding Menu1IsMouseOver}" Value="False" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard />
                  <!-- close animation -->
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard/>
                  <!-- open animation-->
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been racking my brain trying to figure this one out. I really appreciate the help!!!
I found another was to do basically the same thing tho. I made a menu inside a grid and edited the template and did some styling. Then to make it open to the right instead of down I edited a copy of the submenuitem and set the position="Right".  Does what I was looking for but without the animation. Still going to work on that because I thought it was a neat idea.